# How to post an image to facebook page using Google App Script's facebook snippet?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, http-status-code-403

I am trying to setup a small application based on Google App Script and Google sheets 
So far I am able to get the facebook page feed and able to connect to facebook app through Oauth2 library and got the tokens

So I am struggling to write the code for posting to facebook ,

Currently I got the facebook page feeds but the post format documentation from facebook is referring to javascript SDK , and here I am not using SDK and graph API refers with POST and GET requests I think that also didn't work here .
So this is my Codes for getting facebook token and page feed .

Some one referred this as a duplicate but those question and answer doesn't fit in my question , I want facebook post format if it is with payload kindly include those payload options or someone can edit below code for POST

I am able to post to pages with the page access token not user access token
and pasting that page access token also throws the same error .

**Updated Code But error appears as follows**

---

> Request failed for https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/**PAGE**/feed?message=hello?access_token=**TOKEN** returned code 403. Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\n either publish_to_groups permission... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 53, file "FB postinf")

code updated

```
 function example() {

var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess())
   var data = {
    "message" : "Me Testing",
    //"slug" : "me-testing",
   // "text_to_subscribe" : "true"
  };
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : payload
  };
  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/PAGENAME/feed?message=hello?access_token=ManuallyPastedTOKEN";
  // + '?access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(service.getAccessToken());
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  }
```

---

This is using OAuth2 GET FEED

```
function sasublish(){

var service= getService()
if (service.hasAccess()) {

  var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com'
    + '/pagename/feed'
    +'?fields='+ encodeURIComponent("name,full_picture,message,attachments{subattachments,url}")

  +'&access_token='+ service.getAccessToken();


    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});

    var json = response.getContentText();
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(json);
 }
```

Comment: @luschn What is the payload here . Can you refer the payload options available and those  question  is not about facebook graph api. That mentioned question is partially correct but I need the facebook posting format . Like what i should include in the payload .

Comment: @luschn This is the new code but getting 403 error    `function example() {
 
var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess())
   var data = {
    "message" : "Me Testing",
    //"slug" : "me-testing",
   // "text_to_subscribe" : "true"
  };
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : payload
  };
  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/pagename/feed"
   + '?access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(service.getAccessToken());
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  }
`

Comment: the payload is the data (fields to set, access token, ...), you can see it in the duplicate thread. in the question and in the answers. please don´t post code in comments, it´s impossible to read. anyway, it looks correct, what is the exact error message? please update your question with all the details and your current code. and with the detailed error response.

Comment: @luschn  I am able to post to pages before using api . I done this with an wordpress plugin were i able to publish videos as public into my page  with user token but here i couldn't able to post it with the user access token only possible through page token and how we can get the page token by Oauth2

Comment: of course you have to use a page token and not a user token...you want to post to a page, right? how to get a page token is explained in the docs.

Comment: @luschn [link]( https://coderevolution.ro/fbomatic-test/fbomatic-test-generator/) See yourself this is working working with out any issues where i can post into facebook page , which is using php sdk , what i understood from the FB doc is , usertoken is same as page token but we need to use graph api to switch page token how is that possible while we using it in another server .. is that possible via Oauth2 ,to swich tokens

Comment: @luschn updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

Need oAuth2 And Facebook.gs snippet you can use

> .setScope('publish_pages,manage_pages,pages_show_list')

should be added to facebook.gs [link to facebook.gs snippet](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Facebook.gs)

```js
function example() {
var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess())
 var urls ='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/PAGEID?fields=access_token'; //specified page token
   //  var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/accounts?';   //tokens along with pages 
 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls, {       //make url and urls changes
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      }
    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result , null, 2));
   //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result.data[0].access_token))

 
 
 var datas = {
    "message" : "Me Testing",
    //"slug" : "me-testing",
   // "text_to_subscribe" : "true"
  };
  var payload = JSON.stringify(datas);
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : payload
  };
  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/PAGEID/feed"
 + '?access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(result.data[0].access_token);
  // + '?access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(result.access_token);//direct pagetoken
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log('successfully posted to facebook page ',response)
  }
```